# Accelerate framework: calculating pairwise distances of vectors

Tags: swift, euclidean-distance, accelerate-framework

I have N float vectors and I want to calculate the pairwise normalized L2 distance between them. For vectors u and v normalized L2 distance is defined by: `|| u / ||u||_2  - v / ||v||_2 ||_2,  where || ... ||_2 is the L2 norm (i.e. square root of the sum of squares)`

I wrote a class that represents the pairwise distances matrix:

```
class PairwiseDistanceMatrix {

    private let count: Int
    private let buffer: [Float]
    private let bufferPointer: UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>

    let rows: Int
    let columns: Int

    init(with vectors: [[Float]]) {
        count = vectors.count
        let len = vDSP_Length(vectors[0].count)

        var norm: Float = .nan
        var divRes = [Float](repeating: .nan, count: Int(len))

        // Normalizing the vectors: 
        let norms = Array(0..<count).map { (index) -> [Float] in
            vDSP_svesq(vectors[index], 1, &norm, len)
            norm = norm.squareRoot()
            vDSP_vsdiv(vectors[index], 1, &norm, &divRes, 1, len)
            return divRes
        }

        var mutableBuffer = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: count * count)
        let mutableBufferPointer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float>.init(start: &mutableBuffer, count: mutableBuffer.count)

        // Computing the distances between the normalized vectors
        var distancesq: Float = .nan
        for i in 0..<(count - 1) {
            for j in i..<count {
                let index = i * count + j
                let symetricIndex = j * count + i

                vDSP_distancesq(norms[i], 1, norms[j], 1, &distancesq, len)

                mutableBufferPointer[index] = distancesq.squareRoot()
                mutableBufferPointer[symetricIndex] = mutableBufferPointer[index]
            }
        }

        buffer = mutableBuffer
        bufferPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>.init(mutableBufferPointer)

        rows = count
        columns = count
    }

    func elementAt(row: Int, column: Int) -> Float {
        return bufferPointer[row * count + column]
    }
}
```

Currently, for 5000 vectors, this code runs on iPhone X  in ~600 ms. Most of it, as expected takes the nested loops. (Vectors normalization takes less than 2ms).
I'm pretty sure this code can be optimized. Any ideas or directions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore normalization, since that isn't the issue and you already have a reasonably efficient solution.

Assume the vectors are already normalized, then, and we want to fill in the matrix whose ijth entry is ||v_i - v_j||. This can be done more efficiently than your current brute-force method. Observe that

```
||v_i - v_j||^2 = (v_i - v_j)*(v_i - v_j)
                = v_i * v_i - 2 v_i * v_j + v_j * v_j
                = ||v_i||^2 + ||v_j||^2  - 2 v_i * v_j
                = 2(1 - v_i * v_j)
```

So we need to compute the matrix of pairwise dot-products, then apply f(x) = sqrt(2 - 2*x) to each entry of the matrix.

The matrix of pairwise dot products is precisely what we get if we pack the vectors together as rows of a matrix A and compute A*transpose(A), which can be done using the `SSYRK` function provided by BLAS.